# Combo box in form (Access 2010) - Retrieving values from 2 different fields

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to create a Form on access 2010 that navigates among records from a table (`t_main`)

but the problem is that I need a combo to select among `param1_old` and new and also among `param2_old` and new.

This combo will have 2 values, the old and the new for each parameter. In the end, after I select which parameters I want to keep for this user, I will click in a button and save this information into a new table (`t_saved`).

`t_main` has the following structure:

```
user; date; name; param1_old; param1_new; param2_old; param2_new
```

and
`t_saved` has the following structure:

```
user; date; name; param1; param2
```

Any idea on how to do that? Should I work with recordsets? is there a way to avoid it and just force the combo to take values from 2 different fields into a value list?

Thanks a lot for any help!

edit:
I know it is rather complex to understand what I need, I will try to show in a screenshot:

the data in the table are as following:

`user; date; name; param1_old; param1_new; param2_old; param2_new
1234568789;"21/07/2014";"John Smith";'Lemon street 125';'Avocado avenue 123'; '...'; '..'`

[image: Please see this sample]

Comment: Your description makes very little sense to me. Can you please edit your post with some example data, and the result you wish to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention what is the primary key in each tables, so I will assume it's the `user` field and that each record in `t_main` and `t_saved` has a unique `user`.
If not, then substitute that with the actual primary key.

Note that `date` is a reserved keyword and you cannot name a field `date`, so I renamed it `thedate` instead.

I have created a [small sample database](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/52900980/StackOverflow/SO25032098.accdb) that works as you describe (at least as I understand it).

I created these tables with some sample data:

[image: Table t_main]

[image: Table t_saved]

[image: Sampel data in t_main]

I created a form bound to the `t_main` table:

[image: FormMain]

Note that the dropdown boxes `cbParam1` and `cbParam2` are not bound to any field, they are left *unbound*.

The rowsource for the dropdown boxes is a bit of a hack, but it works well.
For instance, for `cbParam1.RowSource`:

```
SELECT param1_old 
FROM t_main 
WHERE user=Forms![FormMain]![User]

UNION ALL 

SELECT param1_new 
FROM t_main 
WHERE user=Forms![FormMain]![User];
```

This query selects both the old and new fields from the `t_main` record that has the same `user` as the one currently displayed. In effect, it shows both old and new parameters for the current record in the combobox.

The code behind the `FormMain` is mostly used to manage the display.
Here we prevent the user from adding the data to `t_saved` if one f the dropdown boxes is empty, or if we've already added that record before.

[image]

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' We use this variable to keep track of whether the
' record was already found in the t_saved table
Private alreadysaved As Boolean

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Update the UI after we change our selection of parameter
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub cbParam1_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateUI
End Sub

Private Sub cbParam2_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateUI
End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Enable/Disable the save button.
' The button is only enabled if the user selected both parameters
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub UpdateUI()
    btAddData.Enabled = Not (IsNull(cbParam1) Or IsNull(cbParam2)) _
                        And Not alreadysaved
End Sub

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Refresh teh data every time we change record
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub Form_Current()
    ' Reset the values of the parameters comboboxes
    cbParam1 = Null
    cbParam2 = Null
    cbParam1.Requery
    cbParam2.Requery

    ' Check if there is already a record for the same user in the t_save table
    alreadysaved = DCount("user", "t_saved", "user='" & user & "'") > 0

    ' Display a warning to tell the user the current record cannot be saved again
    lblInfo.Visible = alreadysaved

    UpdateUI
End Sub
```

The important bit of code is actually the one that adds the data to a new record int he `t_saved` table:

```
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
' The button was clicked.
' Save the current record data to the t_save table
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Private Sub btAddData_Click()
    ' We create a new new record in t_save and copy our data
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("t_saved", dbOpenDynaset, dbFailOnError)
    With rs
        .AddNew
            !user = user
            !thedate = thedate
            !name = name
            !param1 = cbParam1
            !param2 = cbParam2
        .Update
        .Close
    End With
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

    ' Force the form to refresh itself
    ' This will cause the Form's OnCurrent event to be triggered
    Me.Requery
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot Renaud! I didn't have the time to implement everything yet, but it is exactly what I wanted and I hope that on the coming days I will finish it. Again, thanks for all the effort in documenting and making everything clear. Thanks a lot!